# VBA - Loop Security Groups for a Specific User

Tags: vba

I have built a function that checks if a user is member of a security group. Currently it loops all the groups but I would like it loop only the user's groups. I tried to change the function but it keeps giving me a Type Mismatch error.

There is a **SecurityGroups** property for the object **ScUser**. When I use it in the For Each loop it gives me a type mismatch error.
**For Each SecGroup In ScUser.SecurityGroups**

The code below works fine. How would you modify it so it loops only the user's group?

```
Public Function UserHasAccess(SGroup As String) As Boolean

    Dim ScUser As CUser
    Dim SecGroup As CSecurityGroup
    Dim SecGroups As CSecurityGroups

    Set ScUser = New CUser
    ScUser.Init SessionContext
    ScUser.Load SessionContext.CurrentUserID

    Set SecGroups = New CSecurityGroups
    SecGroups.Init SessionContext

    For Each SecGroup In SecGroups

        Debug.Print SecGroup.Fields(SecurityGroup_fld_NAME)

        If SecGroup.Fields(SecurityGroup_fld_NAME) = SGroup Then
            UserHasAccessNEW = True
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next

End Function
```

Comment: "Works fine" and "throws a type mismatch error" are quite contradictory. Mind clarifying?

Comment: It works fine yes, but it loops all the security groups. I only want it to loop a particular user's security groups.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I think the OP is saying that the posted code works fine, but changing the loop to be `For Each SecGroup In ScUser.SecurityGroups` gives a type mismatch.

Comment: Have you tried declaring `SecGroup` as a `Variant` - that **may** get past the type mismatch.  Then you could look (in the Watch or Locals window) at what type `SecGroup` is being set to to determine whether it really is a `CSecurityGroup` type.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. See below. Thank you for your help.

Public Function UserHasAccess(ByVal GroupName) As Boolean

```
Dim oGroups As CSecurityGroups
Dim oGroup As CSecurityGroup
Dim oSecUser As CSecurityUser

Set oGroups = New CSecurityGroups
oGroups.Init REApplication.SessionContext

For Each oGroup In oGroups

    If oGroup.Fields(SecurityGroup_fld_NAME) = GroupName Then

        For Each oSecUser In oGroup.SecurityUsers

            If Trim(oSecUser.Fields(SecurityUser_fld_USERS_ID)) = Trim(REApplication.SessionContext.CurrentUserID) Then
                UserHasAccess = True
            End If

        Next oSecUser

    End If

    oGroup.Closedown

Next oGroup

oGroups.Closedown
Set oGroups = Nothing
Set oGroup = Nothing
Set oSecUser = Nothing
```

End Function